texture UV mapping on the wrong side?
Not sure how to explain this. I've tried shift N (Recalculating normals inside and out) But it seems my UV map is on the wrong side. I feel like i need to rotate the UV map but that doesn't seem to be a possibility. Im not the best at blender so i apologise for the lack of knowledge. Thanks!

The preview looks fine

This side doesn't tho

This is what the UV map looked like originally

separating the two sides seemed to make the connecting edge look great

The front side still doesn't look good tho

Hello, Zaki, welcome. This needs clarification. Perhaps describe to us exactly what  is wrong with the result, compared to what you want. Is your illustrated UV map one you generated yourself? I does look at first sight that that the model needs to be unwrapped in a different way for the texture to work.

I figured it out. In the UV editor, i clicked on UV, Unwrap, cube projection and it fixed it!
